# noobs in trouble

Tags: sd-card, noobs

How can I format a sd card with noobs on it? I can read the disk on a Windows computer, can delete files on a Linux computer because they are read only.
It's probably a simple question for you, but I am only starting in this, sorry.

Comment: In my answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67465/raspberry-pi-2-and-3-do-not-boot/67502#67502) I cover the steps to factory reset an SD card on a Windows computer.

Answer (score 1):

Noobs is no longer supported:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md

I assume you want Raspberry Pi OS flashed to an sd card? Use Pi Imager to flash Raspberry Pi OS to an sd card:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/